# Lost Desktop access after upgrade to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

The title says it all really. Many other problems after this disaster of an upgrade from 18.04 but the main one is having access to my desktop which has meant that I cannot use my laptop for anything else other than work done on-line.
I am a pensioner without much terminal time under my belt.
My laptop is Star Lite with 64bit AMD Processor, Intel Pentium (R) CPU N4200 @ 1.10GHz x 4

Comment: Hi, welcome to Askubuntu!  What kind of (exact) problem are you facing?  is it  black screen? or,  what is it?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a normal start-up screen with Applications on the left, but cannot get a finder window to open. So if I type a letter, for example and save it to my Documents folder, then I cannot access it. Or access anything else. My latest attempt has been to re-install 18.04 from a USB stick, but that seems to freeze up my keyboard so that I cannot type my username or password in the end-box.... I'm at a total loss now as to what to do....

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I'm not sure I follow the problem; sorry!

Comment: I can try, but am on my old laptop now that's running Xubuntu, will try firing up the 20.04 again and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah thanks; don't worry - if it dosen't work Ill try to formulate specifics in text mode. :)

Comment: Now it won't fire up at all. I only get black screen with: GNU GRUB version 2.04 (then) Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions. (then) grub>_

Comment: Can you try to type exit? +If needed(type exit and click enter 2 times if grub comes up again) sometimes I've experienced this.

Comment: Am getting "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key" But when I plug the USB (with 18.04) it just repeats the above request....

Comment: Oh I understand;  I'm not very familair with just grub fixing;    I am probably not in a place to try to give suggestions involving grub (Because;I'm too bad at just, grub - ) So; I hope someone knowledgeable can answer this question; again- sorry

Comment: OK, thanks for all your help. At last I have got it booted from the USB stick now, but that's no help with the original problem... I hope someone else can help or I'll need a new laptop.

Comment: If you're not having anything valuable on your problem-machine (The computer that isn't working); You can reinstall Ubuntu on it;

Comment: Not possible I fear. Absolutely nothing now except GNU Grub, am thinking of taking it into a shop to get sorted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm so sorry I couldn't be of any more,  quality help;   I'm really trying but ;  sorry.   Hope you have a good week anyway!     //Will.   -Sorry,